# Refactor this views code

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in one of my views. The problem is I can't figure out how to refactor it into just one for loop. The only difference is the 'item.' part. I need all three variable values in the same template so I don't think I can pass information from the urls.py. Any ideas of how I can rewrite this so I am not repeating myself?

Thanks.

```
def average(request):

    cal_list = []
    cal_list2 = []
    cal_list3 = []

    exams = Test.objects.filter(test__test_name__iexact="one")
    for item in exams:
        cal_list.append(int(item.start))
        result = sum(cal_list) / float(165) * 100
        result = result / len(cal_list)
        result = int(round(result))
        result = str(result) + '%'

    for item in exams:
        cal_list2.append(int(item.s1))
        result2 = sum(cal_list2) / float(165) * 100
        result2 = result2 / len(cal_list2)
        result2 = int(round(result2))
        result2 = str(result2) + '%'

    for item in exams:
        cal_list3.append(int(item.s2))
        result3 = sum(cal_list3) / float(165) * 100
        result3 = result3 / len(cal_list3)
        result3 = int(round(result3))
        result3 = str(result3) + '%'

    return direct_to_template(request, 'a.html', {'result': result, 'result2': result2, 'result3': result3})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a function:

```
def calculate_result(items):
    items = tuple(int(i) for i in items)
    result = sum(items) / 16500.0
    result = result / len(items)
    return '%i' % round(result) + '%'

result0 = calculate_result(item.start for item in exams)
result1 = calculate_result(item.s1 for item in exams)
result2 = calculate_result(item.s2 for item in exams)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. I this works great and I should be able to reuse the concept for similar calculations.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you keep overwriting the `results` value, so you can extrapolate that part:

```
for item in items:
   cal_list.append(int(item.start))
   cal_list2.append(int(item.s1))
   cal_list3.append(int(item.s2))

result = "%s%%" % round((sum(cal_list) / float(165) * 100) / len(cal_list))
result2 = "%s%%" % round((sum(cal_list2) / float(165) * 100) / len(cal_list2))
result3 = "%s%%" % round((sum(cal_list3) / float(165) * 100) / len(cal_list3))
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go for the simplest refactoring, which saved the loop from iterating only on required things and moving the calculation out of the loop.

```
def average(request):

    cal_list = []
    cal_list2 = []
    cal_list3 = []

    exams = Test.objects.filter(test__test_name__iexact="one")
    for item in exams:
        cal_list.append(int(item.start))
        cal_list2.append(int(item.s1))
        cal_list3.append(int(item.s2))

    result = sum(cal_list) / float(165) * 100
    result = result / len(cal_list)
    result = int(round(result))
    result = str(result) + '%'

    result2 = sum(cal_list2) / float(165) * 100
    result2 = result2 / len(cal_list2)
    result2 = int(round(result2))
    result2 = str(result2) + '%'

    result3 = sum(cal_list3) / float(165) * 100
    result3 = result3 / len(cal_list3)
    result3 = int(round(result3))
    result3 = str(result3) + '%'

    return direct_to_template(request, 'a.html', {'result': result, 'result2': result2, 'result3': result3})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `aggregate` to perform the sum at the database layer.

```
from django.db import models

def average(request):
    queryset = Test.objects.filter(test__test_name__iexact="one")
    total = queryset.count()
    results = queryset.aggregate(
        result1=models.Sum('start'),
        result2=models.Sum('s1'),
        result3=models.Sum('s2'))
    def transform(resultsum):
        result = resultsum / float(165) * 100
        result = result / total
        result = int(round(result))
        result = str(result) + '%'
        return result
    result1 = transform(results['result1'])
    result2 = transform(results['result2'])
    result3 = transform(results['result3'])
    return direct_to_template(request, 'a.html', {'result': result1, 'result2': result2, 'result3': result3})
```